# Converting ADC reading to voltage where microcontroller voltage is not fixed

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I have a reading from an ADC that I want to convert to the equivalent voltage. The problem is that my voltage for the the PIC microcontroller is not fixed. It changes between 5V and and 3.6V.

How can I convert my ADC reading to voltage?

The only possibility that I can think of is to connect the supply voltage to another ADC pin, make an algorithm in FW to approximate  the supply voltage based on this value, and then use it to convert my first reading into voltage.

Comment: Which specific microcontroller model do you use?

Comment: Why not just use a 3.3V reference voltage for your ADC? You can get some that use <200uA so should be suitable enough for most battery applications

Comment: "*The only possibility that I think of is to connect supply voltage to another adc pin, ...*" The problem is the ADC reference voltage. If you don't stabilise that at a known reference then all your ADC readings will fluctuate too and you can't do any internal calibration.

Comment: @Tagli  I am using PIC18F24

Comment: @Doodle you mean I should use an external voltage regulator of 3.3V?

Comment: Can't you set ADPREF to VDD and measure the 1.024V FVR channel with ADPCH=0b111111 and ADFVR = 0b10?   Then you can solve the `reading=1024*1.024V/VDD` for `VDD` and calculate it directly as `VDD = 1024 * 1.024/reading`

Comment: See this: 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201321/measuring-battery-voltage-from-microcontroller-using-adc?rq=1#comment422006_201321  -- read the Fixed Voltage Reference as a special ADC channel using battery voltage as a reference, then back-calculate VDD=VFR*1024/reading.

Comment: Here's some code for backing out the VDD from ADC reading the FVR on an Arduino: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/50771/6628

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.  @DaveX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18F24-25Q10-Data-Sheet-DS40001945B.pdf), you can use internal voltage references for the ADC:

[image]

But the voltage is limited according to the supply:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, If I set it to 4.096, my adc reading will not change with the supply voltage?

Comment: It seems you are restricted to 2.048 V or below

Comment: Thank you. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Can't you set ADPREF to VDD and measure the 1.024V FVR channel with ADPCH=0b111111 and ADFVR = 0b10?   Then you can solve the `reading=1024*1.024V/VDD` for `VDD` and calculate it directly as `VDD = 1024 * 1.024/reading`